# Migrating to non-experimental coroutines

Tags: kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, kotlinx.coroutines

I've been trying to migrate from the experimental version of coroutines (0.23.4) to the recently released one (1.0.1).

I also changed my version of Kotlin from 1.2.60 to 1.3.10.

I updated all of the import statements and removed the "experimental" bit from the gradle file.

When I try to compile my project, I get the following error:
Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:

```
class some.package.SomeClassName, unresolved supertypes: kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
```

`SomeClassName` doesn't even contain any reference to a coroutine -- it merely calls a method from a different module which in turn deals with some coroutines.

I tried adding the dependency on the coroutine packages to all of my gradle modules but that didn't help.

The only thing I found that describes a similar problem is [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-28223)
but I can't understand how that would help or why my compilation fails anyway.

Any help please?

Comment: can you share the project?

Comment: Based on this, it looks like you're extending from CoroutineScope. It's hard to tell without the code, though.

Comment: In your migration have you also done all of the other required conversion?
ie: `launch` -> `GlobalScope.launch`, and such? If not, it may be that the old Coroutine code is muddying the waters.

Comment: Adding the kotlinx.coroutines dependency to all of your modules is actually the correct way to fix this issue. Please make sure you run gradle sync after you do that.

Comment: Please also read the migration guide here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md#migration-to-100-version-with-kotlin-13

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it was happening because I was implementing the CoroutineScope in my "core" module and extending the class in the "app" module, which didn't have the coroutines import in build.gradle. Adding the import there as well fixed the problem.